# Компьютер игнорирует загрузочный образ windows при включении

Tags: linux, windows, установка

Здравствуйте, дело в том, что я установил рядом с windows Linux Mint и пробовал переустановить windows dcе было хорошо, потом я полностью снес всё и установил только linux после чего пробовал установить windows и все тоже было хорошо , но вот теперь каккой бы дистрибутив не стоял не важно mint/ubuntu/elementary при включении и через boot меню и через виос выставлял загрузчик, он просто игнорирует это и запускает линукс, чистка жесткого не помогает в случае с чистым жестким выдает следующее (erorr: no such partition.
Entring rescue mode...
grub rescue> _)
пробовал и при установке линукса оставлял место под windows форматировал раздел в ntfs и все так же безнадежно...

Comment: Возможно это поможет - https://habrahabr.ru/post/117661/

Comment: Я бы попробовал записать MBR с помощью например HirenBootCd утилита MbrFix tool, а поверх уже ставил бы grub.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь такой момент: Linux при установке смотрит все разделы на всех дисках (У Вас один HDD?) и формирует меню для grub2 соответствующим образом. Билл Гейтс плевать хотел на всех остальных, затирает SPL и пишет туда свой, который знает только про виндовоз. Linux при этом становится недоступным. Если после этого загрузиться с установочного диска любого  LiveCD и выбрать пункт "Восстановить загрузчик", то ситуация становится нормальной. Однако Вы описали так много переустановок, что сейчас уже трудно найти концы.

Рекомендую следующую последовательность действий:

1. Устанавливаем Windows на ЧАСТЬ HDD
2. Устанавливаем Linux на оставшуюся часть

Всё будет работать отлично.